# Error using optim() in purrr(): vmmin is not finite

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I've received a function from another worker to calculate the height required of a tree to reach a certain height at age 100 (SI). My job is to put this into purrr to calculate what the height will look like for a number of SI and height crossings in order to plot the growth trajectory.

First I create the base function:

```
SI_tall <- function(topheight,  age, si ){
  paramasi <- 25
  parambeta <- 7395.6
  paramb2 <- -1.7829
  refAge <- 100

  d <- parambeta*(paramasi^paramb2)

  r <- (((topheight-d)^2)+(4*parambeta*topheight*(age^paramb2)))^0.5

  ## height at reference age
  h2 <- (topheight+d+r)/ (2+(4*parambeta*(refAge^paramb2)) / (topheight-d+r))

  return(abs(h2 - si))
}
```

To calculate the height for a tree of given age and site index, we use this function in another. The height will be given by

```
my.age  <- 10
my.si <- 30

new.topheight <- function(my.si, my.age){
  optim(par = list(topheight = 10), ## this topheight is just an initial value
                       method = 'L-BFGS-B', fn = SI_tall, si = my.si, age = my.age, lower= 0, upper=100)$par
}
```

This works nicely for each value.
Since I want to draw a trajectory of the growth of each tree, I'll first need to calculate the ages and site indices at a required resolution to plot. I create two vectors to cross:

```
my.age <- seq(0,110, by=0.2)
my.si <- c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35)

si.crossing <- tidyr::crossing(my.age, my.si)

si.crossing %>% group_by(my.age, my.si) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(topheight = map2(.x=my.age, .y=my.si, .f=~new.topheight(my.si=.y, my.age=.x)))
```

Here's the error I get:

> Error in optim(par = list(topheight = 30), method = "BFGS", fn = SI_tall,  : 
>     initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

What's going wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly pass it to `map2_dbl` with `tryCatch` to handle errors.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

si.crossing %>% 
     mutate(topheight = map2_dbl(my.si, my.age, 
              ~tryCatch(new.topheight(.x, .y), error = function(e) NA)))
```

Or use `mapply` in base R :

```
si.crossing$topheight <- mapply(function(x, y) 
     tryCatch(new.topheight(x, y),error = function(e) NA), 
              si.crossing$my.si, si.crossing$my.age)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, Thanks for your reply!

My colleague replied that there were errors in the optim start parameters, which I have changed in the question above. However, when I plot your solution, the new.topheight uses the ages as the SI and vice versa - leading to the following issue: new.topheight(my.si=100, my.age=15) -> 58.5 metres. Do you know why has the function been reversed? I first suspected that it filled the arguments in order, so I swopped the places of my.si and my.age in the map2_dbl call. However this caused error L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'.. Many thanks!

Comment: Ohhh...I see that I reversed the values of `my.age` and `my.si` in `map2_dbl` but if I put it in right place it returns an error. For example, see this doesn't work `new.topheight(si.crossing$my.si[1], si.crossing$my.age[1])` I am not sure how the `optim` function is used here but maybe there are some restrictions for it.

Comment: I realised I could use safe_new.topheight<–safely(new.topheight) to find the error! However, I am left with a list column height, consisting of list(result=c(topheight=....), error=NULL)). How can I unnest this so that I can keep both the calculated result and the error, in different columns? Bless you for taking the time!!

Comment: I updated the answer using `tryCatch` to return `NA` when error is returned, see if that helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Still trying to solve it with safely(), but have created another question for that, as it is of different interest. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61917848/11550980

Answer (score 1):

We  can use `possibly` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
pnew.topheight <- possibly(new.topheight, otherwise = NA)
si.crossing %>% 
    mutate(topheight = map2_dbl(my.si, my.age, pnew.topheight))
```